# I have a little bit confusion in the following answer that is given in a book

Tags: adverbs

Violence takes a heavy toll and affects public life ____ .

Options - Best/worst/hardly/rarely.

Answer is "Best" .

But how can it be instead of worst????

Comment: Books can be wrong. The answer provided makes no sense.

Comment: As Jeff says, it's nonsense!

Comment: The best "answer" would be to use the actual word in the original text (from [Modern Essays, A Gupta, 2009](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Violence+takes+a+heavy+toll+and+affects+public+life%22)) - *Violence takes a heavy toll and affects public life **adversely***. Anyone who thinks ***best*** or ***worst*** could validly replace the original has very limited knowledge of English. If you found that in a book, chuck it away before it affects your learning progress adversely.

Answer (score 1):

### I believe the book is trying to say "the most"

None of the options it provides are good ones. I think it's an error on the book's part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it involves a little bit of common sense. It affects public life best meaning it is the factor that most affects public life. If it was worst it wouldn't be as effective. The best scorer scores more points, the worst scores less.

Comment: Hmmm, to convey the meaning you indicate, that doesn't sound like a common-sense choice of words at all. The meaning you describe should be expressed as you expressed it in your "translation" illustrating what the sentence might mean: "It is the factor that *most* affects public life.

Comment: This is probably what the person who wrote the question had in mind. You could complete this answer by incorporating what Jeff said in a comment or noting that "most" or "greatly" would be a better word to use.